Microsoft.FeatureManagement read freature flags from DB?
Is it possible to use this nuget and read the values from the DB ? I know the ideal is Azure App Configuration service but would like to explore the DB option. And also don't want to have a huge configuration file with all the features stored in appSettings.json
I see there are custom nugets veff but was looking to keep the Microsoft.FeatureManagement nuget
